# Form validation using jquery and javascript codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to validate my form for empty fields but i am not sure what code i should use can someone please direct me
i have tried the following code but its not working

```
$("validate").submit(function(event){
    $(".offset2").each(function(index) {
       if ($(this).val() == 0) {
           $("#error").css({"display": "inline"}).text("Some of the fields are empty");
           event.preventDefault();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to test if a field is "empty" you should test against an empty string, not against 0. The `==` operator actually returns `true` for `"" == 0` _and_ for `"0" == 0`, but if the user actually types a `0` that's obviously not empty...

Answer (score 1):

Just use a plugin.... More flexibility as you grow.

Here's  free one after 1 minute of google.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
if ($(this).val().length == 0) { // .length is missing in your code
    // Show Error
}
// Or
if (!$(this).val()) { // Empty string is consider as false type in JavaScript 
    // Show Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $("validate").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var status=true;
        $(".offset2").each(function(index) {
           if (!$(this).val()) {
               $("#error").css({"display": "inline"}).text("Some of the fields are empty");
               status=false;
           }
        });
        return status;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

aren't you missing a "#" before "validate".

```
   $("#validate").submit(function(event){
        $(".offset2").each(function(index) {
           if ($(this).val() == 0) {
               $("#error").css({"display": "inline"}).text("Some of the fields are empty");
               event.preventDefault();
           }
        });
    }

);
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend H5Validate http://ericleads.com/h5validate/

It allows you to use the proper HTML5 attributes for validation.

Answer (score 0):

@CodeMonkeyForHire suggested using a Plugin.

The most used one is [jQueryValidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). It will let you write markup like this:

```
<input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
```

And then on your submit button you make one single call to validate all elements inside the form:

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
```

There are many other frameworks like [ParselyJs](http://parsleyjs.org/) or [ValidateJs](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/) that you can try out.

P.S. Google is your friend, always look for plugins (probably someone else had the same problem you did)